# How to encode the image file in PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i am using one file upload form field,from that field i want to encode the filename,don't to want to move the any temporary folder,directly i want to insert the database,while display the image directly fetch DB and display the website,I want encode like **data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA**

```html
$path = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);//here i am getting filename
$im = file_get_contents($path);//here i am getting false
$imdata = base64_encode($im); // so can't here encode the filename
$horoscope = array("encode" => $imdata,"path" =>$path,"getcontents" =>$im);
echo json_encode($horoscope);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP uploads the file into a temporary file and tells you where that is in the `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` the `$_FILES['file']['name']` holds the file name that the user called the file on their system, the one they select in the browser.

So if you want to grab the file before you have done a `move_uploaded_file()` on the file use `$_FILES['file']['tmp']`

```
$path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$im = file_get_contents($path);
$imdata = base64_encode($im); 
$horoscope = array("encode" => $imdata,
                   "path" =>$path,
                   "getcontents" =>$im
                  );
echo json_encode($horoscope);
```

I was not sure what you were passing back the `$path` for, so that may still need to be `$_FILES['file']['name']`.

```
$horoscope = array("encode" => $imdata,
                   "path" => $_FILES['file']['name'],
                   "getcontents" => $im
                  );
```

**RE:Comment 1**

I assume you want to store the base64encoded version of the file to the database so that will be `$imdata`

**RE:Comment 2**

To get the extension of the incoming file use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_parts = pathinfo($path);
$extn = $path_parts['extension'];
```

But beware, just because the extension says `.png` is not actual guarantee that it is a `.png` file

Comment: I tried ur code but still i am getting getcontents =>$im//false

Comment: Insteed of see $_FILES['file']['tmp'] this i changed $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] means,now i am getting base64_encode($im); but i want to store the value in DB,now which value i have to store???

Comment: Woops, sorry about the typo. Added something on how to easily get the extension

Comment: $extn = $path_parts['extension']; where u have to mention for $path_parts